# Set selected value in knockout drop down list after populating it with AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, knockout.js

I have a drop down list on a page.  I have knockout data binding on the drop down list.

By default the drop down list does not have any items in it.  I have an AJAX call that works and retrieves the correct list of items for the drop down list.

After the list of items has been retrieved and loaded into the drop down list, how can I set the selected item of the drop down list?

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="options: listOfPossibleValues, value: selectedValue, optionsCaption: 'Select a Value'"></select>

 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: url,
            data: {
                someParameter: someParameterValue
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $.each(response, function (index, center) {
                    self.listOfPossibleValues.push(response[index]);
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log("There has been an error retrieving the values.");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the `selectedValue` as `observable` and set the value like below:

```
self.selectedValue = ko.observable();
self.selectedValue("//what ever property value get from business model");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="options: listOfPossibleValues, value: selectedValue, optionsCaption: 'Select a Value'"></select>

 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: url,
            data: {
                someParameter: someParameterValue
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $.each(response, function (index, center) {
                    self.listOfPossibleValues.push(response[index]);
                });
                //set value here
                $(".form-control").val("xyz123");
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log("There has been an error retrieving the values.");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have selected value bound to knockout variable using `data-bind=...value: selectedValue` then you only need to assign it a new value (the selected one):

```
self.selectedValue('mySelectedValue');
```

Knockout will do the rest for you